# Printing short latex snippets

Tags: printing, command, latex

Is there a way to quickly (render and) print short latex snippets like single equations?

Something similar to

```
echo "Some text" | lpr
```

like

```
make-latex-image "$\frac{some}{equation}$" | command-to-print-images
```

Comment: there is preview-latex, which is part of auctex (in emacs) which lets you view math in an emacs latex buffer.

Comment: I can't seem to find the package, and I want a command-line solution rather than invoking emacs.

Comment: You might want to ask your question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Ketan Yes, but the `command-to-print-images` part concerns U&L.SE more

Answer (score 0):

There are several projects out there (e.g. [mathtex](http://www.forkosh.com/mimetex.html)) that facilitate converting a single LaTeX fragment into an image. However in your case it it probably worth scripting something yourself so you get more options as far as the available LaTeX packages and your output format go. You should be able to whip up a LaTeX template with your desired packages pretty easily, then compile it and use [`dvipng`](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/dvipng/) to generate an image. One you have an image, most Linux and BSD distros have [apsfilter](http://www.apsfilter.org/) already, so passing the image to the printer is as easy as calling `lpr <image_file>`.